# Is there any fault in my assumption that the following class Should be usable in the Visual Studio Component Toolbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, import, components, toolbox

I have a large number of Windows forms components that I have created in one DLL.

I have historically had to import the project in which those reside into other solutions in order to utilize these components.

I am attempting to resolve that problem.

I currently have a definition as follows:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[DesignerCategory("Provectusoft Forms")]
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
[Designer(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.WindowsFormsComponentEditor))]
public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    ...
}
```

And I'm under the impression that in some circumstance, at least one of these class attributes should provide the ability for the toolbox to ingest said components; however, I am encountering the specific error message of:

```
"There are no components in '<path>\Example.dll' that can be placed on the toolbox."
```

I'm curious if anyone has a resolution.

Thank you for your investment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `ToolboxItem` attribute for the form class.
See also: [How to: Create a Toolbox Control That Uses Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712575.aspx)
To ensure that all attributes were applied, right-click on the toolbox and check the "Show All" item. Then you should be able to see your form there.
But I believe that `UserControl` better fits the purpose.

Comment: I'm curious what you're referring to in respect to a UserControl fitting my purpose better.

Comment: I've also tried adding the ToolboxItem attribute now to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, it was just my humble opinion. My new approach is to remove all attributes except these two: `ToolboxItem` and `DesignTimeVisible`. Try this sample project: [link](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2SR1OxxycOIbkVkb05MUUVjcWs&export=download)

Comment: I've actually now deduced the meaning of your suggestion to do this in the context of a UserControl - thank you for the tip.

Comment: After moving this information to my UserControl extension I've still encountered the same issue but I'm still working to resolve it. Thanks, and I'm sure I'll be following up soon.

Comment: No resolution per your recommendations. Thank you though. I'd be open to any further.

Comment: Did you tried the [sample project](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2SR1OxxycOIbkVkb05MUUVjcWs&export=download) from the comment above?

Comment: Oh wow, I actually didn't note that comment. Thank you for the input and no need to apologize; I'll be sure to compare my own implementation against that one and share results. Thank you again.

Comment: Sadly this change didn't yield a resolution for me. I do appreciate your attempt though; but after implementing an exact replication of the provided code I've still yielded no results.

Comment: What results do you expect? My sample just illustrates that you can see the form `MyControl` in the toolbox. I've modified the sample to inherit the component from `UserControl` instead of `Form`. Try it, please: [download](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2SR1OxxycOINWwxWDlfLUVHakk&export=download)

Comment: I will take a look at any modifications to this source; but my expected result is that the control will be drag-and-droppable from the VS toolbox. I've reached a point where - in the project that these components exist; they've now disappeared entirely from the toolbox - an issue that I am sure I can find a resolution to; but one that indicates ( obviously I suppose ) that the items aren't being properly loaded by the designer.